# Cyanogenmod: custom port not booting (stuck before boot animation)

Tags: android, boot, cyanogenmod, rom

I'm currently building a custom cyanogen port (CM 12.1) for a china phone (Mann Zug 5S for that matter). I've been able to build a working recovery and I've been able to build a ROM. The ROM installed fine so far, but as it gets to booting, I'm stuck *before* the boot animation begins. Only a static image is displayed.

I tried to find some information via `/proc/last_kmsg` (in CWMR), but I did not find any differences to the output with a working stock ROM.

I'd very grateful for any ideas or hints where to look and what to try to narrow down the issue.

Best regards,
Phil

Answer (score 1):

I'm stuck in the same issue. During the boot can you access to logcat with 
`adb logcat` or can you see your device in `adb devices`?

The problem is that without logcat we cannot log the boot process in order to see what goes wrong!

I suggest you to check also these logfiles, if you have them:

- `/cache/recovery/last_log`
- `/proc/kmsg`
- `/dev/log`

Other hints if you are using a stock kernel image:

- Did you import every proprietary libraries (.so files in `/system/lib` and `/system/vendor/lib` folders)?
- Did you import proprietary executables (in `/system/bin`)?
- Did you import every other vendor files you think can be involved in the boot process (in `/system/vendor` and other folders)?

I'm trying this roadmap to get my rom booting. I hope it helps

Comment: Did you manage to fix the problem? I have the same problem.